# Problema con código de javaScript

Tags: html, jquery

La sentencia `if` siempre devuelve `false` cuando esta debería ser `true` para que se ejecute la primera parte del código. Sé que tengo un error en la sentencia `if` porque es lo único que no se ejecuta.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button-menu').on('click', function(){

        if ($('#button-menu').attr('class') == 'fa fa-bars') {
            $('#button-menu').removeClass('fa fa-bars').addClass('fa fa-window-close');
        } else {
            $('#button-menu').removeClass('fa fa-window-close').addClass('fa fa-bars');
        }       
    });
});
```

Este es el código `html` donde está el botón y el menú lateral con sus respectivos submenús.

```
<script src="../js/jquery-3.2.js"></script>
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <span id="button-menu" class="fa fa-bars"></span>
        <nav class= "navegacion" >
            <ul class="menu" >
                <li class="title-menu">CATEGORIAS</li>

                <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home icon-menu" ></span> Inicio</a></li>
                <li class = "item-submenu">
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-balance-scale icon-menu"></span> Nomina</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li class="title-menu"><span class="fa fa-balance-scale icon-menu" ></span>Nomina</li>
                        <li class="go-back">Atras</li>

                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-check-square icon-menu"></span> Autorizacion</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-question-circle icon-menu"></span> Consulta</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-credit-card icon-menu"></span> Persepciones</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-address-book icon-menu" ></span> Innovacion +TI</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguien que pueda ayudarme a ver en donde está mi error, ya que, no encuentro esa falla.

Comment: Podrías poner también el elemento #button-menu en tu código de ejemplo?

Comment: listo  ya lo puse

Comment: pero debes de darle editar a tu pregunta, no agregarlo como una respuesta, compañero

Comment: no me deja dice que es mucho codigo que tenga que describir mas mi problema

Comment: por eso lo puse asi espero y me puedas ayudar el primer codigo que subi es el de jquery y el segundo es el codigo html

Comment: Entonces @Luis trata de seguir la recomendación del sistema no agregues tanto código y explica mas lo que ocurre

Comment: pues es lo que hice y asi lo subi

Comment: listo alguien me puede ayudar con ese problema ya lo edite

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [problemas con codigo javascrip y html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/324108/problemas-con-codigo-javascrip-y-html)

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente creo que el problema está en el js. Ya que estás usando jQuery, te comento que este tiene un método llamado `.hasClass()` que puedes usar para validar si un elemento tiene una clase en específico, este te devuelve un valor booleano `True` o `False`.

Esta es la documentación oficial, donde explican más a fondo el funcionamiento del método [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) y [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Por ejemplo, en tu caso la validación sería algo así:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#button-menu').on('click', function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('fa fa-bars')) {
            $(this).removeClass('fa fa-bars').addClass('fa fa-window-close');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('fa fa-window-close').addClass('fa fa-bars');
        }
    });
});
```

Por cierto, dentro de la función `.on()` estoy usando la variable `$(this)` que hace referencia al botón `$('#button-menu')`, es una buena práctica a tomar en cuenta.

Puedes ver el **ejemplo** que hice en codepen [aquí](https://codepen.io/0x0010b/pen/ExarByw).

Espero te sirva, estoy atento a tus comentarios.

Comment: si me funciono pero solo una vez, tengo que recargar la pagina para volver hacerlo, y no debería de pasar eso, deberia de poder darle clck muchas veces y seguir abriendo y cerrando el menu

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puCuB0j03s4      ---estoy siguiendo ese ejemplo y fue el que me dio error

Comment: Es necesario, @Luis, que en orden de que te queden claros los conceptos, leas la documentación oficial, debido a que hay cosas que no se explican en los videos, además de que no abarcan diferentes caso de uso de tu script. Por otro lado, 0x0010b por favor retro alimenta tu respuesta con bibliografía, replicando también el error si es posible y poniendo enlaces externos en orden que la respuesta le quede clara al preguntador.

Comment: es que solo segui el ejemplo de ese video pero pues ya no pude continuar por ese error que a mi me arroja y deberas si me gustaria que me pudieran ayudar

Comment: @Luis disculpa la demora, repliqué el código en codepen y me funcionó perfectamente, puedes checarlo [acá](https://codepen.io/0x0010b/pen/ExarByw)

Comment: @Luis Cuando se agregan elementos dinámicamente se debe usar el método [$( selector ).bind()](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) para asignar los eventos a los nuevos elementos.

Comment: ta me funciono muchisimas gracias :)