# problemas con codigo javascrip y html

Tags: javascript, html

La sentencia del **if** solo me devuelve un valor negativo y debería ser verdadero para que me hiciera lo primero y sé que tengo un error en la sentencia **if** por que es lo único que no se ejecuta.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#button-menu').on('click', function(){
            if ($('#button-menu').attr('class') == 'fa fa-bars') {
                $('#button-menu').removeClass('fa fa-bars').addClass('fa fa-window-close');
            }else{
                $('#button-menu').removeClass('fa fa-window-close').addClass('fa fa-bars');
            }       
        });

    });
```

El otro código que tengo es el que creé en HTML, donde creé el menú lateral con sus respectivos submenú y está la clase del boton donde debería de hacer la función que quiero pero realmente no sé que pude haber hecho mal.

```
     <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.js"></script>
      <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <span id="button-menu" class="fa fa-bars"></span>
            <nav class= "navegacion" >
                <ul class="menu" >
                    <li class="title-menu">CATEGORIAS</li>

                    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home icon-menu" ></span> Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class = "item-submenu">
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-balance-scale icon-menu"></span> Nomina</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li class="title-menu"><span class="fa fa-balance-scale icon-menu" ></span>Nomina</li>
                            <li class="go-back">Atras</li>

                            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-check-square icon-menu"></span> Autorizacion</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-question-circle icon-menu"></span> Consulta</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-credit-card icon-menu"></span> Persepciones</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-address-book icon-menu" ></span> Innovacion +TI</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Alguien que pueda ayudarme a ver en dónde esta mi error ya que no encuentro esa falla.

Answer (score 0):

El atributo de class pudiera cambiar y no ser exactamente igual a como lo esperas, en su lugar utiliza `hasClass`

```
if ($('#button-menu').hasClass('fa-bars')) {
}
```

EDICIÓN
Al usar toggleClass se quita y se agrega laclase necesaria.

```
$('#button-menu').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-bars').toggleClass('fa-window-close');
    });
```

Comment: le puse el .hasClass en igual de .attr pero sigue igual no me hace nada

Comment: if($('#button-menu').hasClass('class') == 'fa fa-bars') {

Comment: No, la sentencia del if debe ser como te lo propongo

Comment: si lo hizo amigo cambio pero solo cambio una vez y debería cambiar cada vez que yo seleccione el botón no solo una vez y es lo que hace si cambia pero si le vuelvo a seleccionar ya no necesito recargar la pagina para que lo vuelva hacer

Comment: tu sabes por que sucede eso?

Comment: Se cierra el menu si haces click en un área que no sea éste?

Comment: no, no me refiero a eso, a lo que me refiero es que si lo habre pero solo una vez ya no lo vuleve hacer a menos de que recargues la pagina otra vez me explique

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puCuB0j03s4

Comment: estoy siguiendo ese ejemplo pero es el que esta mal

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta editada

Comment: pero vuelvo a lo mismo solo lo hace una vez no lo hace n veces

Comment: tengo que borrar el if y ponerlo asi como tu lo pusiste?

Comment: Si, debes cambiarlo todo

Comment: ya lo hice pero solo hace lo que te comento lo cambia una vez y deberia de cambiarlo n veces solamente me habre el menu una vez y para volverlo utilizar lo tengo que volver a cargar

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y mostrar tu avance

Comment: el avance es que solo cambia una vez y ocupo que cambia muchas veces

Comment: Lo se, pedí un avance en código

Comment: ya me funciono muchisimas gracias